# Is there a difference between ODBC and IBM.Data.DB2?

Tags: c#, .net, database, db2, odbc

I am connecting to a very large DB2 data warehouse within a small C# 2010 application.  I have only used MS Sql in the past.

Is there a difference using ODBC for database calls vs IBM.Data.DB2 ?

Comment: If you were using MS SQL I hope you were using SQLClient.  At a high level they should behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IBM Data Server provider for .Net (IBM.Data.DB2) is the [recommended choice](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0024472.html?lang=en), because it usually offers better performance and richer functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In theory they are just data providers.  With MS SQL you were most likely using SQL Client.  Both DbDataReader and SQLDataReader both implement DataReader so in theory at that level they are the same.